# Combinatorics: Painting identical cards with different colours

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can we paint $n$ identical cards with $k$ different colours in both these cases:

- Only one of the sides painted
- Both sides painted

Comment: What do you mean by "equal" cards? Do you mean identical?

Comment: like, let's say that i paint first yellow and the second one blue:

yellow,blue=blue,yellow

Comment: I think the first one can be solved with the stars-and-bars method. Essentially you are counting how many cards are painted by each colour, and they must sum up to $n$.

Comment: Can you be a little more explicit, didn't you mean 'sum up to k' instead 'n'?

Comment: I mean specifically $n$ because there are $n$ cards. So it's the same as finding the number of integer solutions to
$$
x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_k = n
$$
where $x_i$ is how many cards there are of colour $i$.

Comment: Thanks for your help :). I'm really grateful